# Evaluate xpath2.0 in node.js

Tags: node.js, xpath, xpath-2.0, saxon-js

How to evaluate xpath2.0 in node.js
I found saxon-js and xpath2.js libraries in npm.
I tried as per the documentation but it didn't work.
Give me some examples of how to evaluate xpath2.0 in node.js

Comment: Please don't tell us that something "doesn't work". Tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed, and then there's a chance someone can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon-JS does indeed implement XPath 2.0 in Javascript (actually, XPath 3.1), but it's not currently available for Node.js "out of the box". We hope to ship that in the coming months. People have made it work, but only by digging in and getting your hands dirty.

I can't comment on the current state of Sergey Ilinsky's XPath2 implementation.

Comment: Do you know any library which evaluate xpath2.0 ? In node.js

Comment: None other than those you mention.

Comment: fontoxpath looks as if it is quite an active project though the implementation is incomplete. You could give it a try and report back.

Comment: "for" and "If-Else" expression worked with fontoxpath but replace, tokenize functions are not supported.